# Site template 'An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread'

Tags: 2010, error, site-template

The following error occurs when trying to save a site template:

> An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.

This has been driving me mad so if anybody has encountered this before it would be a big help - if it is relevant this is a SP2010 site and is running on ssl.

Regards,
Craig

Comment: Has it been customised? If so, what sorts of customisations are there?

Comment: Do you have any details in the ULS logs?

Comment: This happens on all subsites so would customisations matter? Shortly after I started to attempt to save this is logged                                                                  Error encountered in background cache check Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: There are no addresses available for this application.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoundRobinServiceLoadBalancer.BeginOperation()